# python 3.8 - dynamically set properties to a class when it's initialized

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, attributes, metaclass

I'm trying to create a class whose instances can have an arbitrary number of attributes. This can be easily achieved using `**kwargs` in the ****init**** method. Then, for each of its attributes I need to count the access throughout the entire lifecycle of an instance.

If I had a *property* for each attributes, then I could increment a counter in both *getter* and *setter* methods for that attribute accessed at a given time.

The problem is that I need to create those properties dynamically, because I don't know which attributes an instance of my class will have.

I'm sure this can be solved by mean of `metaclasses`. Although, I'm trying to address that **without** them.

I've written this code so far:

```
class CountAttr:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # here I init the counter for each keyword argument
        self.__count = {attr: 0 for attr in kwargs}
        # then I add the attribute to my instance
        for kwarg in kwargs:
            object.__setattr__(self, '_' + kwarg, kwargs[kwarg])
            def getter(self):
                self.__count[kwarg] +=1
                return object.__getattribute__(self, '_' + kwarg)
            def setter(self, value):
                self.__count[kwarg] +=1
                object.__setattr__(self, '_' + kwarg, kwargs[kwarg], value)
            #here comes the issue: the property doesn't work
            object.__setattr__(self, kwarg, property(getter, setter))

    @property
    def count(self):
        return self.__count

test = CountAttr(x=5, y=6)

print(test.x, test.y)
```

Debugging my code, I've assessed that `test` has attribute `_x` with value of `5`, as well as attribute `_y` with value of `6`. `x` and `y` are shown as `property objects`, so everything seems to work fine. But it doesn't at the end.

Indeed, the final print statement will output this:

`<property object at 0x7fbb241d4b30> <property object at 0x7fbb241d4b80>`

While the output I'm expecting is: `5 6`, that is, the value of `_x` and `_y` attributes.

Comment: The problem is that the usage of `property()` is different from what you try to do. Normally it would be `x = property(getter, setter)` **directly** in the **class** and not `self.x = property(getter, setter)` inside a method.

Comment: using the class instead of the instance seems to work: `setattr(CountAttr, kwarg, property(getter, setter))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All attribute access in an object in Python, regardless of how the attribute is actually stored in memory (or even if it is computed), goes trough two special methods in the class `__setattr__` and `__getattribute__`.

That is it - just put your counter code in those two methods, use a separate name as instance attribute to store the counter data itself, and go on - no need for fiddling with a metaclass. All you need is a base (or mixin) class with this counter code.  If you don't want the initial setup of the arguments to be counted, you can just start the count from "-1" for writting, for example.

```py
class CounterBase:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._counters = {}
        for name, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, name, value)
        super().__init__()
        
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name != "_counters":
            _counters = self._counters
            _counters[name] = _counters.get(name, 0) + 1
        return super().__getattribute__(name)
        
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name != "_counters":
            _counters = self._counters
            _counters[name] = _counters.get(name, 0) + 1
        return super().__setattr__(name, value)
```

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly, but I wanted to use properties in order to add a level of *information hiding*, thus preventing direct access to "private" attirbute as `_x`

Comment: A property just works at the class level - to use properties with a differing set of attributes per instance, you also need a **new class** for each instance, otherwise all attributes will accumulate as properties on the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use globals, you can do this with a global dict:

```
_count = {}

class CountAttr:
    
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        for i, j in kw.items():
            object.__setattr__(self, i, j)
        global _count
        _count = {i: 0 for i in kw.keys()}
    
    def __getattribute__(self, key):
        global _count
        if key in _count:
            _count[key] += 1
        return object.__getattribute__(self, key)
    
    def __setattr__(self, key, val):
        global _count
        _count[key] += 1
        return object.__setattr__(self, key, val)
    
    @property
    def count(self):
        return _count  # expose count dict interface
```

Usage:

```
>>> test = CountAttr(x=5, y=6)
>>> test.x
5
>>> test.y
6
>>> test.count['x']
1
>>> test.count['y']
1
```

Following with @jsbueno's answer, you can set `count` to the instance as long as you're careful with ordering in `__init__`:

```
class CountAttr:
    
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.count = {i: 0 for i in kw.keys()}  # If <- isn't first 
        for i, j in kw.items():                 # you will get an 
            setattr(self, i, j)                 # `AttributeError`.
        super().__init__()
    
    def __getattribute__(self, key):
        if key != 'count':
            counter = self.count 
            counter[key] += 1
        return super().__getattribute__(key)
    
    def __setattr__(self, key, val):
        if key != 'count':
            counter = self.count 
            counter[key] += 1
        return super().__setattr__(key, val
```

Comment: Ok, it's fine although I did't want to involve globals. I do not understand why `self._count[key] += 1` doesn't work

Comment: This resets all counters for each instance of the class created.

Comment: @jsbueno that is true but there are ways around it.

Comment: @dc_Bita98 that is my fault, I'm not too comfortable with overriding `__getattribute__` so I couldn't figure out how to do that and not get a `RecursionError` (from calling `self._count`). However, @jsbueno's solution is clever and you can incorporate it or just use theirs.

Answer (score 0):

As @Wups noted, setting class attribute instead of instance attribute helps the situation. [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-property-function/) they show an example, how to set encapsulated attribute using property() function. value is a class attribute, value of which is what property() returns. So, in your loop you could create this class attribute passing property() with proper setter and getter as a value. I'd also not declare setters and getter for each kwarg repetitively in a loop, as you can declare them once, but as the name for each kwarg differs, you can encapsulate them in outer functions, which will take this name as a parameter, and then return a function with a proper name of attribute set.

This example seems to be working, as you want it to:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for item in kwargs:
            setattr(SomeClass, item, property(self.getter(item),
                self.setter(item, kwargs[item])))

            setattr(self, '__'+item, kwargs[item])

    def setter(self, name: str, value):
        def inner_setter(self, value):
            setattr(self, '__'+name, value)
        return inner_setter

    def getter(self, name: str):
        def inner_getter(self):
            return getattr(self, '__'+name)
        return inner_getter

inst = SomeClass(r=2, s=4)

print(inst.r, inst.s)
```

Output:

```
2 4
```

Comment: I've added the `counter` logic inside getter and  setter method and now works as I wanted. Thank you

Comment: As I commented in my answer: if this works for you, ok - but you have to be aware that properties are registered on the class and are cumulative for each instance created.

Comment: Actually - this code is just broken:  an attribute re-using the same name in a new class will  overwrite the `property` created in a previous instance - and the previous instance setter code will just stop working. The settr and getter in the example code are empty, but as soon as you attach a counter, you will see what I mean,.

Comment: (sorry: -1 for broken code- I will be watching for fixes)

Comment: @jsbueno Might have not understood you, but no, it does not. This
inst1 = SomeClass(r=2, s=4)

print(inst1.r, inst1.s)
print(inst1.count)

inst2 = SomeClass(r=1, s=5)

print(inst1.count)
print(inst1.r, inst1.s)
print(inst1.count)

inst1.r = 6

print(inst1.r, inst1.s)

print(inst1.count)
inst2.s = 77
print(inst1.count)

print(inst1.r, inst1.s)
print(inst2.r, inst2.s)

gives following output

2 4
{'r': 1, 's': 1}
{'r': 1, 's': 1}
2 4
{'r': 2, 's': 2}
6 4
{'r': 4, 's': 3}
{'r': 4, 's': 3}
6 4
1 77

nothing got overwritten in first instance, count is fine.

Comment: @jsbueno pardon for the messy comment.

Comment: you could just put the code for the counter in the answer  - yes, ".count" can be set per instance, but it is not in your answer. And nonetheless, the class will accumulate one property for each name that is passed as a parameter, in any instance. (also, the "__" name mangling mechanism is not triggered when used like this, you can use just "_")